# Make function generic - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, generics, protocols

I have a function to fetch data that I want to make generic. There are 3 possible classes, lets call them:

- ClassOne
- ClassTwo
- ClassThree

Here is the function that currently works with one class, but it is not reusable with all classes. The problem is the type casting. If I have a parameter and use that parameter for type casting, then it will return an error saying it is not a type. In this function I used type casting  `as! [ClassOne]` and I don't know how to make this generic for all classes.

```
    func fetchFromCoreData() {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: ClassOne)

    do {

        let fetchedEntity = try appDelegate().coreDataStack.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [ClassOne]

        // Do something with fetchedEntity
        currentlyReadingSet = fetchedEntity.first

    } catch let error as NSError {

        print("Could not fetch: \(error)")
    }
}
```

I want to create one function that can be used for all three classes.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you know how generics work in swift? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html

Comment: @UlyssesR I've already read that and I know how to create the basic examples they show, like for example create a generic function that can add not only Int, but also Strings and other things. I don't know how to do generic type casting -- is this possible or is this even the correct way to think about it?

Comment: Are you saying you want to do _exactly the same thing_ with all three classes?

Comment: @matt Thanks so much for responding. That is correct, it should do exactly the same thing for all three classes.

Comment: So if all three classes have enough in common that that's possible, abstract that commonality out as their superclass (or as a protocol, I suppose).

Comment: @matt I'm not very experienced, what you say makes sense but not sure if it would be harder for me to do. What I have now works perfectly, it's just that I have to copy and paste it three times and change only one part of the code: `as! [ClassOne]`, I don't know how to put `ClassTwo` or `ClassThree` in there as type casting. My goal is just to not duplicate code. Am I on the right track, is this possible, to make type casting like this generic?

Comment: I didn't understand any of what you just said. If ClassOne, ClassTwo, and ClassThree are all subclasses of ClassSuper, or if they all implement a protocol MyProtocol, then you just say `as! [ClassSuper]` or `as! [MyProtocol]` once and there you are. If you've abstracted the commonality out into ClassSuper or MyProtocol, you'll be able to do what you want to do to this instance, regardless of whether it is in fact a ClassOne, a ClassTwo, or a ClassThree.

Comment: @matt gotcha, I see what you mean now. Current;y, I do not have a superclass or protocol so I'll have to do one or the other. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behold the power of subclasses. Here we prepare three classes deriving from a superclass that expresses something they can all do:

```
class MySuper: NSObject {
    func thingTheyAllCanDo() {
        print("I did it and I am a \(self.dynamicType)")
    }
}
class ClassOne : MySuper {
}
class ClassTwo : MySuper {
}
class ClassThree : MySuper {
}
```

Now here is some code that does something to instances of all three classes, regardless of which it is:

```
let arr : [MySuper] = [ClassOne(), ClassTwo(), ClassThree()]
for aMySuper in arr {
    aMySuper.thingTheyAllCanDo()
}
```

Output:

```
I did it and I am a ClassOne
I did it and I am a ClassTwo
I did it and I am a ClassThree
```

Isn't that really all you mean here by "generic"?